# Set up a development environment on Linux targeting Linux and Windows

Tags: windows, linux, cross-platform, development-environment

For a university course I have to write a http server which is supposed to run on both Linux and Windows.
I have got a humble Linux machine which I don't think can handle any kind of heavy virtual environment, neither I'm willing to go through the hassle of installing it.

This is the first project of mine complex enough (I estimate ~1.5 months to develop) to require an environment sufficiently comfortable to alternate rapidly between short coding and testing sessions (the latter on both platforms, of course).

So, I was wondering what could be the best set up for this situation. I think testing it on Wine would be ok (it is not a real-world thing, after all), and I installed MinGW for the Windows-targeting part.

Basically, a simple well-written makefile could solve my problem... It should build both the Linux and Windows binaries and place them in the respective folders (the Windows one in the Wine sub-tree) and I'm all done! But I feel very inexperienced in this thing and I really don't know where to start. Maybe the make manual, ahah!:)

Thoughts, suggestions, anything I didn't think/know!
Thank you!

(PS. I'm planning to use emacs as editor, or maybe learn vim. Unless eclipse provide some kind of skynet-like plugin that entirely solve this problem...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. It's not that complicated, really, thanks to MinGW. You basically need two things:

1. The code has to be portable across the OSes. MinGW has some POSIX support, but you'll probably need to either use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) in order to be able to use the POSIX interface or have your own compatibility layer for interfacing with the OS. I'd probably go for Cygwin as then you can code only against POSIX and won't have to test and debug your compatibility layer. Also, make sure you won't use any external libraries that are OS specific. Non-portable code often results in a compile error, but make sure you test the application thoroughly anyway.
2. The toolchains for targeting Linux and Windows. You already have them, you just need to use them correctly. Normally you'd use a variable like $(CROSS_COMPILE) as a prefix when calling the toolchain during cross compilation. So when compiling for Linux, you call gcc, ld, etc. (having the CROSS_COMPILE variable empty), and when compiling for Windows you call e.g. i486-mingw32-gcc, i486-mingw32-ld etc., i.e. CROSS_COMPILE=i486-mingw32-. Or just just define CC, LD etc. depending on the target.

I wrote a small game on Linux and made it run on Windows as well. If you [browse the code](https://github.com/anttisalonen/kingdoms), you can see the code has next to no #ifdef jungle (basically just some extra debugging features enabled for Linux), and the Makefile is simple as well, with no complicated handling for cross-compilation, just the possibility to override CC etc. like it should be. As lots of important open source software is written this way (especially software that's used by the desktop and embedded devices), you should also be able to find lots of other examples on how to set up the build environment correctly.

As for testing the application on Windows, I think the best option is if you can find a real Windows machine somehow. If you do everything correctly, it should run the same as on Linux and you won't need to continuously test your application on both OSes. If testing on a Windows machine is not possible, a VM would be the next best choice, though it would probably be more difficult to set it up. Wine is a good backup plan, but I don't think you can be sure your application works well on Windows if you only tested it on Wine.

Comment: Since when does MinGW provide a POSIX implementation for Windows? Reference??