# make: pattern rule not applied?

Tags: c, makefile

Follow-up: [Set up a development environment on Linux targeting Linux and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9040880/348406)

The project dir looks like this:

```
/pps
    /src
    /obj
    /bin
    Makefile
```

And the content of Makefile is this:

```
OBJ_DIR = obj
SRC_DIR = src
BIN_DIR = bin

INCLUDE = -I./$(SRC_DIR)
LIBS = 

_SRCS = print_current_dir.c test_main.c

_OBJS = print_current_dir.o test_main.o

SRCS = $(addprefix $(SRC_DIR)/,$(_SRCS))
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(_OBJS))

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) -c -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$@ $< $(CFLAGS)

all: $(BIN_DIR)/pps-linux $(BIN_DIR)/pps-win32

$(BIN_DIR)/pps-linux: $(OBJS)
    CC = cc
    CFLAGS = -g -Wall $(INCLUDE) $(LIBS)

$(BIN_DIR)/pps-win32: $(OBJS)
    CC = i586-mingw32msvc-cc
    CFLAGS = -g -Wall $(INCLUDE) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(SRC_DIR)/~ core $(BIN_DIR)/*
```

The files print_current_dir.c and test_main.c are just for testing.

This makefile doesn't work:

```
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `obj/print_current_dir.o', needed by `bin/pps-linux'.  Stop.
```

I think the problem is with the %.o rule. I'm sure it is trivial, but I'm not very experienced with make.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that if you type `make` without specifying a target, the first one in the file is used by default.  So you probably don't want `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o` as your first target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rule:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c %.h
```

specifies that `obj/foo.o` depends on `foo.c`, not `src/foo.c`.  There is no `foo.c`, so this rule cannot be applied (hence the error message).

This should do the job:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(SRC_DIR)/%.h
```